# Kendo Grid Filterable cell

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a requirement in which I have to show two dropdown list in the Filterable cell of kendo grid. These two dropdown lists would filter two different columns in the kendo grid.

One thought I had is having template which would be some kendo container like some panel probably, and then add two dropdowns to that container.

Is this even possible? If yes how to achieve this?

Here is my kendo grid definition.

```
ctrl.mainGridOptions = {
    dataSource: ctrl.gridDataSource,
    columns: [
                {
                    title: 'Col1-Col2',
                    field: 'Col1',
                    width: 200,
                    template: kendo.template($("#col1").html()),
                    filterable: { cell: { template: ctrl.coonetemplate, showOperators: false } }
                },
                {
                    field: 'Col3',
                    width: 150,
                    title: 'Col3',
                    template: kendo.template($("#col3").html()),
                    filterable: { cell: { template: ctrl.colthreeTemplate, showOperators: false } }
                }
         ]
      }
```

Here is a mockup of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: And what you have tried in that template? You're in the right path, you need to create those dropdowns in the `dataBound` event, I think. Anyway, your grid looks wierd. Those dropdowns would appear only in the first row?

Comment: I was able to get one dropdown list cause its easy, but was not able to get the second drop downlist. I agree that the grid looks wierd, but thats how it is. And yes the drop downs should appear in the filter cell of the grid. I believe that the filter cell is not treated as a data row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different parts to this.

First, if you want to have multiple filter controls for different pieces of data, you should define a column for each one.  Then, put a template on the first column to have it display the data for two columns.  Use the attributes option to set a `colspan=2`.  Then, use the attributes option on the second columns to set `style="display:none"`.

The second part is getting the dropdowns.  I generally prefer to use the `values` option to accomplish this.  The code below uses this for the `OrderID` column.  The other alternative was the approach you were on, which is to use the cell template.  The code below uses this on the `ShipName` column.

```html
<div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                OrderID: { type: "string" },
                                Freight: { type: "number" },
                                ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 20,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                },
                height: 550,
                filterable: {
                    mode: "row"
                },
                pageable: true,
                columns: [
                {
                    field: "OrderID",
                    width: 150,
                    attributes: {
                        colspan: 2
                    },
                    values: [
                        {text: "10248", value: "one"},
                        {text:"10249", value: "two"}
                    ],
                    template: '#:OrderID# (#:ShipName#)',
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "eq",
                            showOperators: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    attributes: {
                        style: "display:none"
                    },
                    field: "ShipName",
                    width: 200,
                    title: "Ship Name",
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            template: function(args) {
                                args.element.kendoDropDownList({
                                    dataSource: args.dataSource,
                                    dataTextField: "ShipName",
                                    dataValueField: "ShipName",
                                    valuePrimitive: true
                                });
                            },
                            operator: "eq",
                            showOperators: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Freight",
                    width: 255,
                    filterable: false
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

[Runnable Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@bmulhollem/upuXA)

Comment: Thank you Brady, and upvote for the solution. I will try this and see if it is acceptable by BU.

Comment: Thanks again Brady. I added `attributes` as well as `headerAttributes` and it shows the cols as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Grid filterable cell with custom options column wise and by using this solution it also overwrites general filters settings in case specific column requirement. ASP.NET MVC C#.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.columnName)
    .Format("{0}%")
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb
        .Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true))
        .Extra(false)
        .Operators(op => op
            .ForNumber(fn => fn
                .Clear()
                .IsEqualTo(CommonResource.GridFilter_IsEqualTo)
            )
        )
    )
    .Title("Column Name");
```